# App to sort through every file on Mac?

Tags: macos, finder, applications

I'm switching to a new computer and want to sort though my files to back up some of them. Basically, I'm looking for a Mac feature or app that I can use to sort through every user-generated file. I want all of my files in a list with an option to save or delete each one, without having to sort through folders and hidden files and non user-generated files.

Does this exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to back up every file that was created by you. If that is the case, all your files should be in /Users/Username. You can simply go to Disk Utility, hit `Shift + Command + N` and select the `/Users` directory if you would like to backup multiple users or just select the `/Users/Username` directory for one user and then make a Disk Image. Be aware that this will also back up the app data for the users selected.

Comment: No I don't need to back up every file; rather, I need to see every file on my computer in a list to be able to either back them up individually or delete them.

Answer (score 0):

> a Mac feature or app that I can use to sort through every user-generated file. I want all of my files in a list with an option to save or delete each one, without having to sort through folders and hidden files and non user-generated files.

A utility like **Disk Inventory X** might be useful just to see the expanse of your hard drive.

Or, if you wanted an explicit list thereof (but again, without this save/delete convenience), you could look into some variation of this **Terminal** command:

```
find -E -s . -name ".?*" -prune -o -iregex '.*\.(app|dmg|pkg)' -print -prune -o -print | LC_ALL=C sort -f
```

That is, it lists all files on your volume (ignoring those prefixed by . and ignoring all files contained in application package contents), sorting within each directory, case-insensitive.